Browser remembering previous logged in account in MSAL iOS
I have integrated with the MSAL iOS library.
Few issues I have trouble resolving.
When I call signout as follows
        [self.mMSALApplication signoutWithAccount:currentAccount signoutParameters:signoutParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
            if(callback) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    callback(YES);
                });
            }
        }];

The user is signed out fine. However when I start the interactive acquiring token process the browser pops up with the prompt "Are you trying to sign in to MyAPP?" and the continue button automatically signs them in.
Now I know I can force a login by
  parameters.promptType = MSALPromptTypeLogin;

However the issue I have is that is seems like the device itself seems to know the previous account so I am thinking this isn't really secure if the app/device will be shared by multiple users.
I have tried getting the accounts and deleting them, but that didn't seem to make any difference.
I tried the
 signoutParameters.signoutFromBrowser = YES;

But that just seems confusing that the user has to select the account to sign out from.
How to handle this in an elegant way?

After you create the MSALWebViewParameters instance you are going to use, you can set its prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession property to true.  This will prevent the web authentication session from sharing cookies - Effectively a private browser session will be used.
There is a trade-off to this, however; The user will always need to enter their login details.
This may be better for shared devices, butit is worse for personal devices. You need to consider what is best understanding the use case for your app.

Thanks will try this. Through MDM I will have an app config that can be marked if the app is shared and do this only if it is shared.
